# Synchronizing multiple delete statements without the use of "GO" keyword

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got a decent sized cleanup query here that is nothing but 15 or so lines of `DELETE` statements. I've noticed that the last few lines sometimes fail due to FK reference constraints but as soon as I re-run the query, the remaining data is deleted. My research has led me to believe this is a timing issue. I can't however add `GO` after each statement because my variables lose scope...

```
DECLARE @userOrders TABLE(OrderId INT)
DECLARE @userInventoryCatalog TABLE(InventoryId INT)
DECLARE @userSpotCheckRequests TABLE(SpotCheckRequestId INT)

INSERT INTO @userOrders
SELECT OrderId FROM [Order] WHERE UserId = @userId

INSERT INTO @userInventoryCatalog
SELECT InventoryId FROM [Inventory] WHERE UserId = @userId

INSERT INTO @userInventoryCatalog
SELECT SpotCheckRequestId FROM SpotCheckRequest WHERE InventoryId IN (SELECT 
* FROM @userInventoryCatalog)

DELETE FROM ClientCustomerNotes WHERE ClientCustomerId IN (SELECT 
ClientCustomerId FROM ClientCustomers WHERE UserId = @userId)
DELETE FROM InventoryShelveMapping WHERE InventoryId IN (SELECT * FROM 
@userInventoryCatalog)
DELETE FROM UserBinAllocationLog WHERE UserId = @userId
DELETE FROM OrderMantoxTeaInventory WHERE MantoxTeaInventoryId IN (SELECT * 
FROM @userInventoryCatalog)
DELETE FROM InventoryLog WHERE InventoryId IN (SELECT * FROM 
@userInventoryCatalog)
DELETE FROM Analytics WHERE UserId = @userId
DELETE FROM SpotCheckRequestItems WHERE SpotCheckRequestId IN (SELECT * FROM 
@userSpotCheckRequests)
DELETE FROM SpotCheckRequest WHERE InventoryId IN (SELECT * FROM 
@userInventoryCatalog)
DELETE FROM UserNonReturnableItems WHERE InventoryId IN (SELECT * FROM 
@userInventoryCatalog)
DELETE FROM InventoryBundleDefinition WHERE InventoryId IN (SELECT * FROM 
@userInventoryCatalog)
DELETE FROM Inventory WHERE UserId = @userId
DELETE FROM [Log] WHERE OrderId IN (SELECT * FROM @userOrders)
DELETE FROM OrderTracking WHERE OrderId IN (SELECT * FROM @userOrders)
DELETE FROM OrderProperties WHERE OrderId IN (SELECT * FROM @userOrders)
DELETE FROM OrderDimensions WHERE OrderId IN (SELECT * FROM @userOrders)
DELETE FROM OrderAttachments WHERE OrderId IN (SELECT * FROM @userOrders)
DELETE FROM OrderPicker WHERE OrderId IN (SELECT * FROM @userOrders)
DELETE FROM OrderZenDesk WHERE OrderId IN (SELECT * FROM @userOrders)
DELETE FROM OrderReprocessingQueue WHERE OrderId IN (SELECT * FROM 
@userOrders)
DELETE FROM OrderPicker WHERE OrderId IN (SELECT * FROM @userOrders)
DELETE FROM OrderInformation WHERE OrderId IN (SELECT * FROM @userOrders)
DELETE FROM [Notification] WHERE UserId = @userId
DELETE FROM [TransactionPaymentLog] WHERE UserId = @userId
DELETE FROM [TransactionLog] WHERE UserId = @userId
DELETE FROM [Order] WHERE UserId = @userId
DELETE FROM UserContacts WHERE UserId = @userId
DELETE FROM ClientCustomers WHERE UserId = @userId
```

So my question is:
**How can I make sure multiple statements run synchronously?**

Comment: Are you sure that the tables are being processed in the correct order to avoid foreign key issues? Are there any triggers that might be introducing problems, e.g. updating the log tables? SQL Server will execute the statements in order, one at a time. (You didn't tag the question as applying to a specific database.) There are 27 `DELETE` statements, somewhat more than "15 or so".

Comment: Sorry. It is MS SQL. Any yea I eye balled that one hehe. But no there are no triggers. I am sure they are being processed correctly as this used to work. It fails randomly. Seems the more data there is the more likely it is to fail. When I first put this in there were only a couple hundred rows to test on, now there are thousands and thousands and it's only now that this problem has creeped up.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `isolation level` and set transaction and execute the `delete` statement. It will make sure that the values are not updated, when you are working on deletions, so that `delete` happens synchronously.

`set transaction isolation level repeatable read
BEGIN transaction
DELETE Statements....
COMMIT transaction`

You can also read [more about isolation levels](http://www.besttechtools.com/articles/article/sql-server-isolation-levels-by-example).